# No response from AJAX request Zend framework

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

> Here is my Controller:

```
    public function listAction()
{
    $this->_flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
    $this->view->messages = $this->_flashMessenger->getMessages();

    $this->view->targetUrl = BASE_URL . "beheer/page/list/populate";
}
```

> and the get-data action is following

```
public function populateAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();

    $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $message = [$request['message']];

    $data = ['ok'];
    echo $this->_helper->json->sendJson($data);
    exit;
}
```

> Here is my list view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function() {
        var message = $('#message').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $this->targetUrl ?>",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            data: message,
            success: function (data) {

                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert('error');
                console.log(error);

            }
        });

        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <input type = "text" name="message" id="message">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

I have checked in my Console and it shows whole html.Ajax function looks ok but i didn't get any Json response. I didn't know why. Please help me. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to Zend documentation (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), you can send JSON response using either of the following (copied from their site)

```
// Direct helper call
$this->_helper->json($data, true, array('keepLayouts' => true);

// ...or, call a method of the helper
$this->_helper->sendJson($data, array('keepLayouts' => true));
```

So your code should be like this...

```
public function populateAction()
{
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();

    $request = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $message = [$request['message']];

    $data = ['ok'];
    echo $this->_helper->sendJson($data); // modified this part
    exit;
}
```